# Sitecore ECM Newsletter: links to site doesn't work from mail Inbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I've created ECM NewsLetter with some links to site (another Items). In online version of NewsLetter links works fine, but when I've sent this NewsLetter to my email and tried to click  on links from my mail Inbox it's displays 404 not found error. Base URL - The default address for all links configured properly. What am I missing? Maybe some configuration? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you check the source in the e-mail and see what the link is pointing to?

Comment: and if send Newsletter by click on Test button - links work. In e-mail inbox link looks like: site.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=%2mypage.aspx&ec_camp=00000000000000000000000000000000&ec_as=00000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: if send Newsletter by click on Dispatch message button - links don't work. In e-mail inbox link looks like:site.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=%2mypage.aspx&ec_camp=6CDF958396FE4C6DABBC318860DFA7A3&ec_as=F829E136B63042CB9927100E3C0BF2D1

Comment: I think you're having the same issue as another user reported here on SO.  Check out my reply to that  issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846392/sitecore-ecm-newsletter-ecm-generate-different-values-for-links-inside-message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to check here:

Most likely source is that the campaign item that gets created when the email is sent is not published.

If the campaign is published then check the goal that gets installed as part of the ECM module is published: /sitecore/system/Marketing Center/Goals/Click Email Link

The way to test the source of the problem is to search for the guids in the link querystring - the ec_camp part of the querystringis the guid of the campaign. Search for this in your content delivery web databse - if this exists then check the goal mentioned above. The ec_as value is the value used to identify the user in the analytics db. This wont exist in your sitecore tree.

finally if both of the above work then follow this set up guide and ensure all the relevant ECM pages are installed properly on your CD servers - including the connection string to the ECM service that handles all tracking and link processing: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-magnified/posts/2013/09/ecm-on-cd.aspx

Comment: there was an issue with Analytics database

Answer (score 1):

If you view source are they absolute links?  If not one thing we did was create a newsletter device and detect we were coming from ecm.  Then we could specify an alternative layout/sublayouts/data sources based on device.

The sublayouts could check if they were coming from a newsletter device and ensure they return all links absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Within the ECM you need to make sure that you are saving and publishing as you move throughout the process of setting up and deploying a message. Once the message is edited, save and publish the message. Before dispatching, you should smart publish the target audience which in turn will re-publish the message. Then, when you dispatch you should see all the images.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the configuration of Email Campaign Manager. Follow these steps

1. Go to Email Campaign Manager.
2. Select Content tab.
3. Check the value of Base URL- default address for all links field.

If it is set to some website URL other than your website URL change it to your website URL.