# Sitecore ECM Newsletter: ECM generate different values for links inside message when click on Dispatch and Test button

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I have ECM NewsLetter with some links to site (another Items). When I send this Newsletter to my email by click on Dispatch button - links don't work when I click on them from the email inbox. It displays 404 not found error. But in ECM, if I click on Test button and type an email address, then go to inbox - the links works.
Link - when clicked on Dispatch message button looks like: (after ec_camp there's no nulls)

```
http://www.site.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=mypage.aspx&ec_camp=6CDF958396FE4C6DABBC318860DFA7A3&ec_as=F829E136B63042CB9927100E3C0BF2D1
```

And link - when clicked on Test button looks like: (after ec_camp there's a lot of nulls)

```
http://www.site.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=mypage.aspx&ec_camp=00000000000000000000000000000000&ec_as=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why does this happen? Only the last link works. How to generate a proper link when clicked on Dispatch message button?  I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you have separate CD + CM environments and also that you're using ECM 2.x as well.

If this is the case, we had the same issue and it's apparently a bug in ECM.  When you dispatch, the campaign, message, etc are all already created, but they aren't published to the shared Web database automatically. (as one might expect)  Sitecore support was able to provide us with a fix for this.

Contact support and reference issue ID `388472`.

Also: The zeros are there for the campaignID and automation state when you send the test email so that it doesn't log your test against your actual campaign.

Comment: No, CD and CM are not separated. And have ECM 1.33

Comment: Interesting; okay.  Could still be the same issue that may have existed in 1.33.  Try creating your message right up to the point where you're ready to dispatch it.  Then publish everything related to the message.  Then dispatch and see if it works.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but publishing haven't solved the problem. I also have checked if it exists in Web database. Do you have any other ideas why links don't work?

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed in [the latest ECM version](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Resources/Sitecore%206/ECM%20Module/ECM%202.1.aspx). I just updated it and tested with Sitecore 7.1. (it is ECM v2.1 rev.140214 ).

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a CM and CD environment? Are you sure that both url's points to the same domain?

Make sure you have the file /sitecore/redirecturlpage.aspx on all your environments. Make sure that the item mypage.aspx is pointing to is actually published.

Don't worry about the zeroes in the ec_camp querystring. These are simply there to trigger a campaign in DMS. It will not cause a 404.

Comment: CD and CM are not separated